# Load a downscaled image with Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Android-Universal-Image-Loader to load an image into an imageView. Is it possible to show a downscaled version of the image i am loading while the original image has not yet loaded?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042297/how-to-show-image-preview-while-downloading-it-on-android), the way to achieve your goal would be prepare and download two images, one with less size to show as preview while the big one is downloading